# DAX - IF lookup value empty return column value

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I'm using Power Pivot 2013, I have two table.

(fact)Table A: Name and Value
(dim) Table B: Name and Type

When selecting pivottable, I want to show Type and Value but if Name.TableA can't be found in Name.TableB, instead of returning (blank) i want pivottable to return Name.TableA. I have tried VALUES() IF(VALUES) with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the source for TableA and TableB? Did you load through Power Query?

Comment: For Table A its through Power Query for Table B, its defined in a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

i think that you have created a relation between name.tableA and name.TableB. You can Create a calculated column on TABLEA using related(Type.TableB).

At this point if you have a relation between the table in new column on TableA you have some row blank and some row with the TYpe.TableB. If it's working change the column formula with

```
 =if(ISBLANK(related('TableB'[Type]));'tableA'[name];related('TableB'[Type]))
```

If there isn't a connection between table you should change related with Lookup.

Comment: Is that DAX? The syntax doesn't look valid.

Comment: it is an example of structure:

=if(ISBLANK(related('TableB'[Type]));'tableA'[name];related('TableB'[Type]))

Comment: but your code in your answer is different and had . not [] so please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use a named variable inside the measure for that:

```
var mylookup = LOOKUPVALUE(
      dim[name]
    , dim[id]
    , fact_table[id]
    ) 
    return IF( NOT ISBLANK (mylookup), mylookup, "UFO")
```

[UFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidentified_flying_object) value will be returned either:

1. if dim table contains NULL in the dim[name] field,
2. if there is no match for [id] in dim table.

See more [DAX VAR defining named variables in the middle of the measure code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57769750/1903793)